# how to set first line color in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview

How can I set only the first line color in a gridView? I tried to use this code, but this works well until I scroll in the grid, than I have multiple cells set with my color. 
Can anyone help me with this?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    }

    if (position == 0)
        view.setBackgroundColor(0x30FF0000);
    return view;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of View reuse. `convertView` that is popped out when you scroll is the same recycled View that comes out from the other side. So it still has the background previously set. You can add this line to prevent this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    }

    if (position == 0)
        view.setBackgroundColor(0x30FF0000);
    else  view.setBackgroundColor(/*default color for the other rows*/);
    return view;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if (position == 0)
        view.setBackgroundColor(0x30FF0000);
  else
    view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

The adapter always have cache